# (x, 0) in the negative half space

Tags: classification

My course textbook writes this about weight spaces when talking about linear classification:
[image].

Why would $w^{T}x$ be considered to be in the negative half space if 0 is not less than 0?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68138/what-does-mathbfwtxw-0-graphically-mean-in-the-discriminant-function/81920#81920

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)#Upper_and_lower_half-spaces

Comment: The text says "good region" and "bad region" and not "negative half space". The point is just that you have two half-spaces..